# How to generate all possibilities of objects of 2 dimensions

Tags: python, list, permutation

I have to generate all the possibilities of objects put in stacks like this:

- There are n objects and b stacks
- I care about their position in the stack

For example, if we only cared about what stack they are in, and we have 3 objects and 2 stacks, we can make an array of

(0, 1, 1) - this means object 1 is in stack 0, the rest are in stack 1

Generating all the combinations is just (0,0,0) (0,0,1) and so on.

If I actually need to know what is on top of what in the stack, then I can't know this way

What I think of is also to have a stack order variable so for the case of (0, 1, 1), it would be

((0,0), (1,0), (1,1)) or ((0,0), (1,1), (1,0)) , so the first variable for each is where it is and the second is its order and 0 is lowest

How to generate all the possibilities in python? (so (0,1,1) would have 2 permutations and (1,1,1) has 6)

Is my representation of ((a,b),...) efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different representation might be simpler: Consider your different stacks as regions in one big stack, then the distribution of elements over the stacks can be seen as (a) a permutation of all the elements, and (b) the partition of that permutation into the different stacks. For instance, for `n=5` and `b=3`, one such partition of a permutation might be `[4 3 | 1 | 2 5]`, i.e. the first stack is `[4, 3]`, the second just `[1]`, and the third `[2, 5]`.

```
import itertools

def partitions(lst, minim, num_part):
    if not lst and num_part == 0:
        yield []
    elif lst and num_part > 0:
        for i in range(minim, len(lst) + 1):
            for p in partitions(lst[i:], minim, num_part-1):
                yield [lst[:i]] + p

def distribute(n, b):
    for perm in itertools.permutations(range(n)):
        yield from partitions(perm, 1, b)

for x in distribute(5, 3):
    print(x)
```

Results (some of 720 for `n=5` and `b=3`, with at least one element per stack (`minim=1`))

```
[(0,), (1,), (2, 3, 4)]
[(0,), (1, 2), (3, 4)]
....
[(2, 3), (0, 1), (4,)]
...
[(4, 3, 2), (1,), (0,)]
```

And if you need the `(stack, position)` format, it should not be too hard to transform the result into that format in a post-processing step.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As a question, how can I know the topmost element in the stack in your format. In other words, how can I point to the last element in each group. Also, one point that's important that I can't figure out in your case: the stacks are not unique so order is not important, so 0 | 1 2 is same as 1 2 | 0 how can this be achieved?

Comment: Also, can you please edit the code with a maximum number per stack rather than min?

Comment: @SolvingPy For the maximum number, you could just loop over `range(minim, min(maxim, len(lst)) + 1):`. For the "stack order is not important" thing: Not sure how to handle this while generating the stacks, but you could just create a `set` of `sets` of permutations in postprocessing.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to fix the issue where an extra comma is after groups (example here [(0,), (1, 2), (3, 4)]) of single objects

Comment: @SolvingPy That is not an issue, that's just how one-elemented tuples are printed (or created). Remember that `(x)` would just be `x`, whereas `(x,)` is like `[x]`, just as a `tuple` instead of a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the combinations using `itertools` like this:

```
>>> prod = itertools.product(range(3), range(2), range(5))
>>> [x for x in prod]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 4), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 4), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (1, 0, 4), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 4), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 0, 3), (2, 0, 4), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 1, 4)]
```

Depending on the numbers this may be very inefficient, but for small values it will be okay.

Comment: my question is it doesnt make sense to generate stacks orders that do not exist. So this means for (0,1,1), it would have 2 permutations only as in my question. Second, what is more efficient than this as yes, the numbers are big